# Why NaNs were printed when trying to find Min & Max in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

## load dataset

```
dataImf  = pd.read_csv('/home/anubhav/datasets/lifesat/gdp_per_capita.csv', thousands=',', delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1',na_values='n/a')
```

## collected unique entries in each column.

```
dum11,dum22,dum33 = dataImf.Country.unique() , dataImf['GDP per capita'].unique() , dataImf['Estimates Start After'].unique()
```

## minimum, maximum, length of unique entries & print if required.

```
print(dum22.min(),"-->",dum22.max(),len(dum22),"\n",np.sort(dum22),"\n")
#nan --> nan 188

print(dataImf['GDP per capita'].min(),"-->",dataImf['GDP per capita'].max(),len(dum22),"\n",np.sort(dum22),"\n")
#220.86 --> 101994.093 188

print(dum33.min(),"-->",dum33.max(),len(dum33),"\n",np.sort(dum33),"\n")
#nan --> nan 17

print(dataImf['Estimates Start After'].min(),"-->",dataImf['Estimates Start After'].max(),len(dum33),"\n",np.sort(dum33),"\n")
#0.0 --> 2015.0 17
```

Question: if I take out unique values and then try to get the min. & max., it outputs NaNs, but if I do not apply any unique() method and use the df['col_name'].min() or max(), it output the correct values.? 
(I took distinct values from all 'n' instances of a column to reduce the search for min. or max. function by avoiding redundant searches.) 
Please suggest on why after considering unique() method the output is NaNs.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) returns a numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, np.nan]})

df
Out: 
     A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  NaN

df['A'].unique()
Out: array([  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan])
```

Now the method you call on `df['A'].unique()` will be a numpy method. [`ndarray.min()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html)  returns `nan`  if there are `nan`'s in the array. `pd.Series.min()` returns the minimum ignoring the `nan`'s, however.

If you want to use the array, you need to use `nanmin`:

```
df['A'].unique().min()
Out: nan


np.nanmin(df['A'].unique())
Out: 1.0
```

or convert the result to a Series:

```
pd.Series(df['A'].unique()).min()
Out: 1.0
```